# EF Core, querying data with one-to-one relationship based on an enum

Tags: c#, mysql, database, linq, entity-framework-core

So I have these tables
[image]

The main table here is `entry` which has a field `type`, `type` is an enum it can be `text` or `phrase`, so how do I include to my EF query corresponding data from these tables?

Also would it be better if instead of this enum I were to use another junction table something like `details` to put between entry and different types of details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I include to my EF query corresponding data from these tables?

You can achieve that this way:

```
var result = from e in context.entries
             join t in context.texts
                on e.entryId equals t.entryId into tJ
             from t in tJ.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join p in context.phrases
                on e.entryId equals p.entryId into pJ
             from p in pJ.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 Entry = e,
                 Text = t,
                 Phrase = p
             };
```

In result set, each `Entry` will be loaded with its corresponding `Text` or `Phrase` based on its type and the other field will be null

> Also would it be better if instead of this enum I were to use another junction table something like details to put between entry and different types of details?

You don't need this enum at all. You can use above query to load items with the help of their `entryId`